# Does paid traffic improve SEO?

Tags: seo, traffic

In Fiverr there is a complete subcategory to "[Get Traffic](http://www.fiverr.com/categories/online-marketing/website-traffic#layout=auto&page=1)". Some of the descriptions in the category claim that "these traffic will boost your ranking or your biz". Is it true? How new traffic could improve a website rankings?

Comment: Not worth it, most of it will be bounce. As this kind of traffic is usually done by redirecting users, they are not likely to click on any links in your site.

Comment: Yes, I imagine that these user won't be really interested in the website, but the question is about its SEO impact. Is real? Positive? Negative?

Comment: Page visits with high bounce rates are likely to have adverse effects on seo as it shows this wasn't what the users were looking for. Also the users wont be arriving from SERPs so not sure how this will increase any seo. I certainly havent seen any credible proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never seen any evidence that Google uses traffic to a website as a ranking signal.   There is certainly a bunch of speculation about it [in this thread on WebmasterWorld](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4620228.htm).

If they did, they would have to very careful about it.  Google is the main traffic source for most websites.   Using website traffic as a signal would have to exclude traffic that Google itself sends, otherwise it would be a self-reinforcing feedback loop where Google sends more traffic and sees the website has more traffic, so it sends even more.

There is also the issue of where Google would get the data about which websites have traffic.  Google has several possible sources for this data:

- Google Toolbar
- Google Chrome Browser
- Google Analytics
- Google's malware blacklist
- Google's DNS servers

However, they might be missing out on certain demographics such as Internet Explorer  users.

You could certainly make the case that Google *should* be ranking sites better because the are getting users.  Having users seems like it could be a sign of quality.  A couple years ago I remember reading about an online retailer with a huge ad budget that was trying to make the case that their large ad budget should be considered a sign of quality that Google considers in its rankings.